# Unable to vertically align JLabel with JCheckBox as if single JCheckBox with GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcheckbox, grouplayout

Sometimes I need the label for a checkbox to be to the left of the checkbox not the right so instead of using

```
JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("label",false);
```

I do:

```
JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("",false);
JLabel    label    = new JLabel("label");
GroupLayout.ParallelGroup vp1 = layout.createBaselineGroup(false, false);
vp1.addComponent(checkbox);
vp1.addComponent(label);
```

(I am using GroupLayout)
but they are not vertically aligned correctly, I've also tried

```
 =layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER);
```

which doesn't look bad but still appears different to using a single checkbox
and various other options, is it possible to get the same alignment ?

Comment: Why not use [setHorizontalTextPosition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setHorizontalTextPosition(int))?

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammmer, this is the responsability of setHorizontalTextPosition

Comment: my 2cents and probably not an option - if you have the slightest chance: go for an external LayoutManager

Comment: @MadProgrammer, brilliant didn't realize this method existed, yes that is what I should and will use. Although still (slightly) interested if this can be done with my incorrect method.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I'd follow kleopatra's advice on that.  Yes it can be done. I'd drop the label and checkbox in a pane of there own and use something like `GridBagLayout`, but that might be over kill in this case, `FlowLayout` would work as well

Comment: I dont understand what kleopatra is meaning by 'external' LayoutManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use the function `setHorizontalTextPosition(int textPosition)` with the int value `SwingConstants.RIGHT` etc

Comment: Found a problem if you have a checkbox, and then below have something else like a Jlabel  (for an entry field) and you set alignnment to LEFT then the start of the text for the checkbox is not aligned up with the text of the JLabel. With a default checkobox that has the label to the right the checkbox is not lined up either (its indented slightly)  but that looks okay, however it looks funny when it is text that is not lined up with text.